# Sass compiler Phoenix Framework

Tags: sass, frontend, phoenix-framework

I am new to front-end Phoenix framework and trying to implement Sass, however the “priv/static/css/app.css” is not compiling using “web/static/css/app.scss”. My app.css.map file looks like this:

`{"version":3,"sources":"web/static/css/app.scss","names":[],"mappings":"","file":"priv/static/css/app.css"}`

and my brunch.config file looks like this:

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
    scripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"

      // To use a separate vendor.js bundle, specify two files path
      // https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/config.md#files
      // joinTo: {
      //  "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/,
      //  "js/vendor.js": /^(web\/static\/vendor)|(deps)/
      // }
      //
      // To change the order of concatenation of files, explicitly mention here
      // https://github.com/brunch/brunch/tree/master/docs#concatenation
      // order: {
      //   before: [
      //     "web/static/vendor/js/jquery-2.1.1.js",
      //     "web/static/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      //   ]
      // }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css"
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    // This option sets where we should place non-css and non-js assets in.
    // By default, we set this to "/web/static/assets". Files in this directory
    // will be copied to `paths.public`, which is "priv/static" by default.
    assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/
  },

  // Phoenix paths configuration
  paths: {
    // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
    watched: [
      "web/static",
      "test/static"
    ],

    // Where to compile files to
    public: "priv/static"
  },

  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
    }
    sass: {
      options: {
        includePaths: ['web/static/vendor/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets']
      }
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true,
    // Whitelist the npm deps to be pulled in as front-end assets.
    // All other deps in package. will be excluded from the bundle.
    whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html"]
  }
};
```

I also get an error when I run node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build:

```
25 Apr 09:06:33 - error: Initialization error - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
  at Module.load (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at Promise.then.config (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/lib/application.js:458:18)
  at Object.keys.forEach.environments.forEach.Object.keys.map.exports.install.exports.replaceConfigSlashes.Object.keys.forEach.types.map.type.map.joinTo.map.types.forEach.exports.setConfigDefaults.Object.keys.forEach.normalized.paths.possibleConfigFiles.Object.keys.map.readComponents.then.Promise.then.obj.catch (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/lib/application.js:450:10)
  at Object.keys.forEach.environments.forEach.Object.keys.map.exports.install.exports.replaceConfigSlashes.Object.keys.forEach.types.map.type.map.joinTo.map.types.forEach.exports.setConfigDefaults.Object.keys.forEach.normalized.paths.possibleConfigFiles.Object.keys.map.readComponents.then.Promise.then.exports.loadConfig.tryToLoad.then.config.then.then.then.config.then [as loadConfig] (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/lib/application.js:496:10)
  at new BrunchWatcher (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/lib/watch.js:75:17)
  at Promise.all.then.setProp.constructor.application.loadConfig.then.then.initCompilation.initWatcher.chokidar.watch.on.on.absPath.on.compile.assetErrors.forEach.Promise.all.then.then.watch (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/lib/watch.js:341:10)
  at exports.new.start (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/lib/index.js:27:10)
  at Command.listener (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/commander/index.js:301:8)
  at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
  at Command.emit (events.js:185:7)
  at Command.parseArgs (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/commander/index.js:615:12)
  at Command.parse (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/commander/index.js:458:21)
  at Object.keys.forEach.exports.run (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/lib/cli.js:73:11)
  at loadBrunch (/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch:34:7)
  at /Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch:44:5
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I a junior and new to Phoenix, so apologies if I have make a silly mistake, any advice would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

probably check your file `/Users/dara.carolan/Sites/tomcat/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js` which seems to be malformated :)

Answer (score 0):

In **Phoenix 1.4** sass is implemented using **webpack** as explained [here](https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-1-4-webpack-4-and-bulma-bootstrap-4-sass/14354/7).

1. Install `node-sass` and `sass-loader` in your npm project
2. Update the loader in webpack config: `{test: /\.scss$/, use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]}`
3. Rename `app.css` to `app.scss`
4. Update the import in `app.js` to `import css from "../css/app.scss"`